# Standard usb device into a MTP device

Tags: usb, media-player, usb-mass-storage

How can I convert a USB device, used for storage, into a Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) device which shows up in Windows as a portable media device?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not possible. Try to understand the implementation of MTP then you will get to know why its hard. I assume that USB device you referring is a pendrive/memory card etc. In case of MTP the driver used is gadget driver. There should be a MTP server to be running on USB device which will reply to the query sent by the host PC. If you are referring USB device is a mobile in your case then you need to change driver part. Implement your own MTP server. Android has implemented MTP you can have a look at it.

Comment: yes, it is a standard usb pendrive. can i not copy data onto the pendrive to make the computer think it is portable media?

Comment: No. You can't do that